# How to get original columns name and thems alias name from a view

Tags: sql-server, sql-view

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio (latest version to date) and I have encountered a problem.
I have a view and i need to get the original columns name that we chose with the SELECT and the alias name that we give with the AS.
I tried a lot o methods but noone works.

I leave you the sample code and what I would like to achieve:

Sample code inside the view:

```
 SELECT 
      [Cmpy_Cod]
      , TRIM( SUBSTRING( [K00001], 5, 6 ) ) AS [Machn_Cod]
      , TRIM( SUBSTRING( [F00002], 9, 20 ) ) AS [Machn_Desc]
      , TRIM( SUBSTRING( [K00001], 5, 3 ) ) AS [Machn_WC_Cod]
      , CASE
        WHEN TRIM( SUBSTRING( [K00001], 5, 6 ) ) = '111111' THEN 'AAA'
        WHEN TRIM( SUBSTRING( [K00001], 5, 6 ) ) = '222222' THEN 'BBB'
        WHEN TRIM( SUBSTRING( [K00001], 5, 6 ) ) = '333333' THEN 'CCC'
        WHEN TRIM( SUBSTRING( [K00001], 5, 6 ) ) = '444444' THEN 'DDD'
        WHEN TRIM( SUBSTRING( [K00001], 5, 6 ) ) = '555555' THEN 'EEE'
        WHEN TRIM( SUBSTRING( [K00001], 5, 6 ) ) = '666666' THEN 'FFF'
        WHEN TRIM( SUBSTRING( [K00001], 5, 6 ) ) = '777777' THEN 'GGG'
        WHEN TRIM( SUBSTRING( [K00001], 5, 6 ) ) = '888888' THEN 'HHH'
        ELSE 'N/A'
        END 
        AS [Machn_Dept_Cod]
FROM
    "TABLE_NAME"
```

[This is what I would like to obtain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxDJr.png)

Comment: What happens in the event of  coalesce(col1,col2,col3) as SomeAlias ?   Which column wins?

Comment: Your select is a static query so just create another static query that returns the data using `values` table constructor. Hard to fathom though why you should even need this, sounds like an XYProblem.

Comment: no problem, just create extra view columns called "original column for alias X" and put the string of the original name, and it's smooth sailing all the way to the sunset from there. you can even code the value in the column name and return nulls to save some space like: [original column name for column X is Y]

Comment: If I use COALESCE it returns the Alias name of the columns, not the original one.
I also try differet way to obtain the original columns and the Alias. For example with syscolumns, sysviews , sysobject , INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE and with some joins I obtain a table with the original name and the alias name. But for every Alias I got the match with every original columns that are used in the view

Comment: I also use sql function: sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set ('SELECT * from [CATALOG].[SCHEMA].[VIEW]', null,1).
It returns the name of the columns and the source columns of them (IT DO WHAT I NEED) but it returns the source column only if it's passed to the view in direct way.
In the sample code that I gave in the question I "trasform" the data with SUBSTRING and also with CASE WHEN, and this function doesn't work if the column is not passed in direct way. 
P.S: The parameters of the function I wrote are fictitious, just to give an example

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for doesn't exist. There is no guarantee there is a backing column at all. For example, you can construct a view using only literals, functions calls like `getdate()`, or mixing values from several columns.

Comment: Ok but all the views that I use in my Database use columns of other table. I don't have case where i do not use columns.
 And I give an Alias almost in all the columns. As you can se in the example only Cmpny_Cod doesn't have Alias.

Comment: @FilippoCosta Doesn't matter. That's a constraint you've imposed on yourself rather than anything the database actually knows or cares about. The database still has to assume a view can have different kinds of columns.